# Possibility to recover Microsoft access records if possible not using 3rd party application

Tags: ms-access-2010, recovery, data-recovery

I want to recover microsoft access record i just accidentally deleted it and then save it. is it possible to recover it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Access doesn't offer any built-in data recovery tools.

As for 3rd party programs, as far as I know, there are none that offer this functionality.